# In tableau, how do you modify the number of decimals of a percentage label?

Tags: formatting, decimal, tableau-api

In tableau, how do you modify the number of decimals of a percentage label? On bar charts, histograms, maps, etc.

Comment: I figured it out, yes im a beginner so trying to get the basics down still. I appreciate the willingness to help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Right Click on the measure dropped under Marks Card and Click on "Format". You will be provided with the options to change the format of the numbers in "Pane". Select "Numbers" and Click on the "Percentage" and increase/decrease the Percentage Decimals.

If you want that format choice to be the default for occurrences of that field on all worksheets, set the default property number format by right clicking on the field in the data pane (left margin) instead of on a shelf

Answer (score 4):

In Tableau 2019.3

Right-click on the field name 'pill' in the left-hand column under "Measures,"
then select "**Default Properties**" and then "**Number format**" and then "**Percentage**"

Answer (score 3):

On the target field right-click and then Default Properties > Number Format > Percentage 
and then determine after how many number you want to place your decimal